# Rails what is development cache in rake dev:cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running `rake --tasks`, it shows me

```
rake dev:cache   # Toggle development mode caching on/off
```

I know we have development view cache for some fragments. **Is any anything else Rails does have cache for?** for ex: Db queries

**Also, is it useful for if in production mode we have this cache also?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your `config/environments/development.rb`, in a >= rails 5 application, you should be able to find the following:

```
  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end
```

So the `rails dev:cache` does nothing else than just placing a file in `<Rails.root>/tmp/caching-dev.txt`, which will then enable caching. Here's the implementation of the command: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20961

To see how caching works, checkout the rails documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html